# Does MacPorts keep a log for actions like install and upgrade?

Tags: macports

After I ran `sudo port upgrade outdated` I’d like to know what was upgraded. The output was longer than my scrollback buffer.

I checked `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/` but it seems to only contain logs for some of the compilations, not installation. For example, a copy of the output of `sudo port upgrade outdated` would be nice. Right now I simply `tee` the output to a file, but this kills the nice progress bar since `port` doesn’t see a TTY at the `stdout`.

Answer (score 2):

I will be semi helpful here. I can show you where the data is and an SQL query but you might need more for a clean solution.

Macports keeps a registry in an SQLite database in /opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db This includes a date which looks like to me the time the package was last installed on your machine

An SQL query returns the data

```
SELECT
  ports.name, 
  datetime(ports.date, 'unixepoch')
FROM
  ports
ORDER BY
  ports.date
```

You will need to modify the query for your exact use case to only show a subset (e.g. add a where clause) and something to run it in

A crude way to do this is use sqlite3.

```
sqlite3 /opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db
```

Then you get a prompt - at that paste in the SQL above - then type in ; and hit return

At the bottom I get

```
iTerm2|2021-05-10 09:48:10
openjdk16-zulu|2021-05-10 09:49:00
rust|2021-05-16 09:47:44
```

I have only upgraded rust today

Comment: Thank you! This looks very promising. Is there any field to show whether I install a port from package, or compiling from distfiles? This is shown in the console output during `port upgrade`, but I don’t see it shown in the database. The `installtype` seems to always be “image”.